# How to find out user's 8:00 PM, no matter where the user is located?

Tags: ios, ios7, nsdate, nscalendar, nstimezone

I am implementing `UILocalNotification` to remind the first-time user at 8:00 PM to use the app again. The user can switch it completely off or setup a different time.

I picked 8:00 PM as time after work, so that it is less interrupting or intrusive.

I am not sure how to handle timezones.

If the user is in New York. `[NSDate date]` only returns a GMT datetime (a moment in time since the reference date).  So how do I determine his 8:00 pm?

Could I just do this?

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear| NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitTimeZone) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateComps setHour:20];
[dateComps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

NSDate *result = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `UILocalNotification` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The date specified in fireDate is interpreted according to the value of this property. If you specify nil (the default), the fire date is interpreted as an absolute GMT time, which is suitable for cases such as countdown timers. If you assign a valid NSTimeZone object to this property, the fire date is interpreted as a wall-clock time that is automatically adjusted when there are changes in time zones; an example suitable for this case is an an alarm clock.

So to ensure your notification is set at the same 'wall-clock' time (eg 8pm) regardless of the time zone, just do

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = theDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

Comment: Thanks thats fantastic. If I set the timezone as you suggested to have the 'wall-clock' effect. If I was going to create a recurring daily reminder, where can I lookup what datetime `UILocalNotification` picked? (I want to show that value in a label)

Comment: I believe it is as simple as `[localNotification fireDate]`

Comment: You need to set the `fireDate` property as above, assigning your own `NSDate` object. You can always read back it again later, using `NSDateFormatter` to gain a user-readable date string.